# C++ Beginner - Simple block of code crashing, reason unknown

Tags: c++, oop, crash

Here's a block of code I'm having trouble with.

```
string Game::tradeRandomPieces(Player & player)
{
  string hand = player.getHand();
  string piecesRemoved;
  size_t index;
  //Program crashes while calculating numberOfPiecesToTrade...
  size_t numberOfPiecesToTrade = rand() % hand.size() + 1
  for (; numberOfPiecesToTrade != 0; --numberOfPiecesToTrade)
  {
    index = rand() % hand.size();
    piecesRemoved += hand[index];
    hand.erase(index,1);
  }

  player.removePiecesFromHand(piecesRemoved);
  player.fillHand(_deck);

  return piecesRemoved;
}
```

I believe the code is pretty self explanatory.

`fillhand` and `removepiecesfromhand` are working fine, so that's not it.
I really can't get what's wrong with this :(

Thanks for your time

**EDIT**
OK, I found out where the program crashes. Added a comment to the above source code.

Comment: Where does the crash happen?  Do you have a backtrace?

Comment: Can you provide some more details, like what error is being thrown, what line its dying on, etc?

Comment: does it crash if you comment out `player.removePiecesFromHand(..)` and `player.fillhand(...)`. If so, then you can narrow down which line it is pretty quickly.

Comment: Just the standard "This program stopped responding" Windows error. And I'm running the debug version.

Comment: Not related to your problem specifically, but it looks like you're trying to use a string to store a collection of "pieces", each of which is represented by a character. Why not use a `std::vector` to store your pieces? It would make more logical sense, and would allow you to use something other than `char` to encode your pieces, which could be very useful, depending on what else you're doing.

Comment: any reason you are using strings to keep track of hands rather than std::vector (or std::list)?

Comment: I'm designing a simple scrabble implementation. I really can't see the advantage of a vector vs. a string in my particular case...

Comment: If `player.getHand()` is in the 10's of thousands, I could see this taking a long while.  Otherwise, it seems like it's one of the methods you are calling - try commenting them out individually and see if it still happens (or use those master debugger skills you've been building up!)

Comment: Nope, getHand() will be around 7 chars. Commented the methods out, still crashes...

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code if you're handling the possibility of an empty hand.  I'm assuming you're using Visual Studio, so run the program with debugging from the menu.  Once your program "stops responding", go to the same menu and stop your program.  Single step it from there and you'll see where it's hung up.  Also, I don't see how you can say `fillhand` and `removepiecesfromhand` are working fine but then get fixated on this piece of code that's clearly also working fine by itself.  Probably somewhere you're working on a copy of something and it's not changing like you think.

Comment: indiv, the program crashes while calculating that first random value, outside the for loop. what the hell.

Comment: How did you discover that?  I compiled and ran this program, returning a 10-char hand from my stub Player class and it worked fine.  You may be corrupting the stack or heap elsewhere by overrunning a buffer.  I can confidently say that this particular method isn't your problem though, and you're not chasing the root cause which will take detective work (like printf debugging or breakpoints and monitoring memory locations) to find.

Comment: My program no longer crashes, for some reason. All I did was take the number of pieces to trade generator out of the for declaration. What the hell...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stick a breakpoint into your for loop to give you a better idea of what's going on.  I would bet that the for loop is going infinite and causing the program to hang.

On hitting the breakpoint, check your iterator variables and see if you can see anything out of the ordinary

Comment: Thanks for the check, glad that I could help.  Could you share what the problem was, so that others may benefit from your discovery?

Comment: It was quite odd, actually. I started debugging, first using printf then the actual "debug" function. It only stopped crashing after I took the numberOfPiecesToTrade out of the for loop declaration, as shown in my question.

Answer (score 3):

If the hand is empty, then this operation:

```
rand() % hand.size()
```

In the initializer of the `for` loop, will be attempting to perform a modulus by 0, which is essentially division by zero. That is your crash.

Add a test to make sure the hand is not empty before proceeding with the rest of the method.

Comment: This would not cause 'This program stopped responding'

Comment: It causes a floating point exception, and is definitely a crash bug with this code. I have no idea what message Windows puts up when an FPE is encountered. There may be a second error, but I don't see it. Edit: Or, if for some reason the div-by-zero resulted in a negative number, instead of a crash, it would make the loop infinite. But I don't know why a system would handle an FPE like that.

Comment: Yes, I considered the div by 0 case, and I already had a .empty() test. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use

```
 for (size_t numberOfPiecesToTrade = rand() % hand.size() + 1; numberOfPiecesToTrade > 0; --numberOfPiecesToTrade)
```

to make things clearer.

Edit:
If you run in debug mode, than wo don't you just debug? :)
This "not responding" message is afaik often caused by an infinite loop.

Edit2: 
I don't know if i am correct, but could it be that in some cases you will miss the numberOfPiecesToTrade != 0 condition if the initialvalue of numberOfPiecesToTrade is 1? I'm not familiar with size_t though.

Comment: your edit: Because I don't know how. :( I know, I should learn..
your edit no. 2: No, that's not it.